# How to get the ID of the document in a subcollection?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to do CRUD using the data in the 'food' subcollection but i don't understand how to get the ID of the subcollection
[image]

```
restaurantCollection
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('food')
        .doc(docId)
        .update(data);
```

I understand that this is for updating the fields in the food subcollection, but how do i actually get the `docId`?

```
final CollectionReference restaurantCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('restaurant');

Future addFoodData(String description, String name, double oriPrice,
      double salePrice, int pax) async {
    return await restaurantCollection.doc(uid).collection('food').doc().set({
      'ruid': uid, //i stored the parent's ID in the child
      'name': name,
      'description': description,
      'oriPrice': oriPrice,
      'salePrice': salePrice,
      'pax': pax,
    });
  }

 List<Food> _foodListFromSS(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Food(
        name: doc.data()['name'] ?? '',
        description: doc.data()['description'] ?? '',
        oriPrice: doc.data()['oriPrice'] ?? 0.0,
        salePrice: doc.data()['salePrice'] ?? 0.0,
        pax: doc.data()['pax'] ?? 0,
      );
    }).toList();
  }

Stream<List<Food>> get food {
    return restaurantCollection
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('food')
        .snapshots()
        .map(_foodListFromSS);
  }
```

^database.dart
this is how i've been creating the data.

```
class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MenuState createState() => _MenuState();
}

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  bool loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Users>(context);
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : StreamProvider<List<Food>>.value(
            initialData: [],
            value: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).food,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: ElrAppBar('Menu', false),
              drawer: ElrDrawer(),
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('ADD MENU Pressed');
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MenuAdd(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
              body: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: FoodList(),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

^menu.dart

```
class FoodList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoodListState createState() => _FoodListState();
}

class _FoodListState extends State<FoodList> {
  bool loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final food = Provider.of<List<Food>>(context);
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: food.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MenuUpdate())),
                child: Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
                    child: FoodTile(food: food[index])),
              );
            },
          );
  }
}
```

^food_list.dart

```
class FoodTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Food food;
  FoodTile({this.food});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: colorsConst[900],
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  food.name.inCaps,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),                
                SizedBox(height: 4),
                Container(
                  width: 260,
                  child: Text(
                    food.description.inCaps,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 4),
                foodInfoCard('Original price: ',
                    'RM ${food.oriPrice.toStringAsFixed(2).toString()}'),
                SizedBox(height: 4),
                foodInfoCard('Selling price: ',
                    'RM ${food.salePrice.toStringAsFixed(2).toString()}'),
                SizedBox(height: 4),
                foodInfoCard('Available pax: ', food.pax.toString()),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

^food_tile.dart

here is how i've been getting the list of food from the subcollection.
i dont know how to return only one specific data from the subcollection when i click on the card in food_list.dart.

I'm meeting a dead-end and I'm so lost. I hope there are some that would be glad to help me out.
do ask for more information if needed. thank you in advance!

Comment: You should have that id already stored in your app. You have the uid of the parent category already. And food is constant. How are you getting the original data before updating it? You can't update a document it you don't have it's id. If you are creating a new document in the food subcollection, then use .set

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad That sounds almost like an answer. Would you like to add it so Marini and other future developers can take advantage of it?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad i've added the coding that i used to create and read the docs in the food subcollection. i really dont know how to return the data of one document for me to to CRUD on it. :'(

Comment: @AlexMamo you could share too if you dont mind. hehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have that `id` already stored in your app. You have the `uid` of the parent category already. And `food` is constant. How are you getting the original data before updating it? You can't update a document it you don't have its id. If you are creating a new document in the `food` sub-collection, then use `.set()`.

When you perform this operation:

```
Future addFoodData(String description, String name, double oriPrice,
      double salePrice, int pax) async {
    return await restaurantCollection.doc(uid).collection('food').doc().set({
      'ruid': uid, 
      'id': generateRandowId,//Create an ID and store it here.
      'name': name,
      'description': description,
      'oriPrice': oriPrice,
      'salePrice': salePrice,
      'pax': pax,
    });
  }
```

In the future when you fetch these documents, it'll have an 'ID' field, and you can use that to update it. Because you have the parent `ruid` and `food` and now `id` of the document in the subcollection.
I would also advise you to create objects\models out of these documents. It'll make working with them easier, and less prone to errors when handling `['keys']`.

Comment: alright, i think i get your point. So, i declared a ```var newFoodDoc = restaurantCollection.doc(uid).collection('food').doc();``` and i returned ```return await newFoodDoc.set({'fid': newFoodDoc.id, ... });``` and it worked wonders! thank you so much for the clarification!